# Can 2 inequivalent expressions' Laplace Transforms be equal?

Tags: laplace-transform

Very simple question:

When $f(x) \neq g(x)$, is it possible for $L(f(x)) = L(g(x))$?

Comment: No for the unilateral Laplace transform, and $f=g$ in almost everywhere sense. Yes if bilateral Laplace transform and the domain of convergence is not the same ($f=1_{x> 0}$ and $g=-1_{x < 0}$)

Comment: Keep in mind that the domain is $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: Alright I'm just a differential equations student however I had an exam question in which 2 different expressions yielded the same transform but only on [2,inf). Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

According to Lerch's theorem (see Theorem 2.1 in A. Cohen. Numerical methods for Laplace transform inversion. Springer, 2007), equality of the Laplace transforms of two functions implies that the two functions are equal almost everywhere. That said, we cannot have two functions that are substantially different from one another and have the same Laplace transform.